# How to execute a SQL query for longer time

Tags: database, jdbc, oracle10g

In one environment,the database is slow and query is taking time to run approximately 10 minutes beacause of which other threads are waiting for the object and entire jvm is getting hanged.In order to simulate the issue and to be sure that it is because of longer time for executing query,i want to intentionally run same query for 10 minutes(slowing down my query in my environment).We are using jdbc connectivity.Can anyone please suggest how to slow my query so that it will take 10 to 15 minutes to execute.We are not using query timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using **dbms_lock.sleep( Number_of_seconds )** in your query for delaying?

Comment: For which he'll have to `GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.DBMS_LOCK TO USER;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i have already tried this,but i am able to do insert and update operations in same table and in other tables for the same schema,can you tell me how to block the same and do the same operation through jdbc in java.

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't experienced same scenario but in java and through jdbc commands you can do as well as in for example oracle sql developer also you can use thread.sleep in java codes if you don't want to make the delay in your PL/SQL codes but in java codes. good luck.